# How does backbone.js determine if it is on the server?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

**Snippet**

```
  // Require Underscore, if we're on the server, and it's not already present.
  var _ = root._;
  if (!_ && (typeof require !== 'undefined')) _ = require('underscore');
```

This is directly from the development code.  However I don't see how it can determine this by checking for [underscore.js](http://underscorejs.org/) as this library runs on the both the client and the server.

Comment: Wait i just realized that ur link for underscore.js was for require.js --> was this intentional?

Comment: It all depends on the context @Hiro

Comment: require.js link is **not** relevant to your question at all. whereas to the answer it is.

Comment: I removed the random addition you made to your question. If you want to add an answer, then add an answer in the answers section....

Answer (score 4):

`(typeof require !== 'undefined')` <-- key part of the code.

If you are **not** on the server (or you do not have [require.js](http://requirejs.org/)), this piece of code will not run, since the `require` variable will be `undefined`.

Comment: To elaborate, the assumption is that servers will automatically provide a `require` function. If one is not available, you probably aren't on the server.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc I think that was what I said... but I guess not.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc I added an extra few words to better elaborate.

Comment: @HiroProtagonist no.... If you are using Node.js for example `require` is a default function that you can use...

Comment: @HiroProtagonist so go complain to the backbone devs :-)

Comment: There is not validity to this answer. Both underscore and require may be used in the browser. Hence the answer is completely invalid. I'm not complaining. I'm letting you know your answer has no meaning.